# Running (cumulative) product in R?

Tags: r

```
x <- as.data.frame(1:5)
```

with the above data frame I want to create a new column which has a running product, i.e. the first element should be

```
1*2*3*4*5 = 120 then
2*3*4*5 = 120 then
3*4*5 = 60
```

and so on.

How can I do this in R?

result should be

```
> x[,"result"] <- c(120,120,60,20,5)
> x
  1:5 result
1   1    120
2   2    120
3   3     60
4   4     20
5   5      5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cumprod`

```
rev(cumprod(rev(x[[1]])))
#[1] 120 120  60  20   5
```

Or

```
rev(Reduce(`*`, rev(x[[1]]), accumulate = TRUE))
```

---

Also, there is a convenient wrapper in `accumulate`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
   mutate(result = accumulate(`1:5`, `*`, .dir = "backward"))
#  1:5 result
#1   1    120
#2   2    120
#3   3     60
#4   4     20
#5   5      5
```

Comment: cumprod will only look at 1*2 then 1*2*3 etc rather than what I want

Answer (score 1):

To do so while simply adding a new column to your data:

```
data <- data.frame(list(x = 1:5))
data
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
data$prod <- apply(data,1,function(x) prod(x:5))
  data
  x prod
1 1  120
2 2  120
3 3   60
4 4   20
5 5    5
```

Comment: or `data %>% mutate_at(1, function(x) prod(x:5))` will also compute this by each row